# Best approach to setting up QDialog boxes and retain access to elements in the QDialog?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qdialog

I'm currently running this implementation of QDialog, which works for what I need, but doesn't seem like a best practice approach, and there are flaws that I can't seem to work around. I know QDialog can be implemented as a Class or Method, but I need to be able to access elements of QDialog like `QLineEdit` and `QComboBox`, and I'm not sure how to do this other than the code I have listed below. All of the values associated with the `QComboBox` in the `QDialog` are applied immediately, so there is no need to keep a copy of the QDialog around after it has been closed.

> Test.py

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

Ui_MainWindow = uic.loadUiType('TestMainWindow.ui')[0]
Ui_ExampleDialog = uic.loadUiType('TestExampleDialog.ui')[0]


class ExampleDialog(QDialog, Ui_ExampleDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=Qt.Dialog):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, flags=Qt.Window):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('MCVE')

        # THIS DOES NOT SEEM APPROPRIATE, BUT I NEED TO ACCESS
        # ELEMENTS OF THE UI FILE OUTSIDE OF 'showExampleDialog'
        self.exampleDialog = ExampleDialog()

        self.itemInfoBtn.clicked.connect(self.showExampleDialog)
        self.setupItemInfo()

    def showExampleDialog(self):
        # ACCORDING TO PYCHARM 'self' IS 'QMainWindow',
        # DO I ASSUME THAT 'parent = QMainWindow'?
        self.exampleDialog.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.exampleDialog.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.exampleDialog.accept)
        self.exampleDialog.exec_()  # CREATES A TASKBAR ENTRY ... BUT WHY?

    def setupItemInfo(self):
        # THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF HOW I'M CURRENTLY ACCESSING
        # ELEMENTS OF THE `showExampleDialog' DIALOG
        val = {'Entry #3', 'Entry #2', 'Entry #1'}
        self.exampleDialog.setWindowTitle('Example Dialog')
        self.exampleDialog.exampleCombo.insertItems(0, val)
        self.exampleDialog.exampleCombo.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> TestMainWindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>282</width>
    <height>173</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="itemInfoBtn">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>ItemInfoBtn</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

> TestExampleDialog.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::ApplicationModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>174</width>
    <height>98</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="modal">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="Message">
     <property name="text">
      <string>I'm a Dialog ...</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
  <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QComboBox" name="exampleCombo"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="closeButton">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Close</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

One of the issues I have is that `QDialog` creates a second taskbar entry beside the `QMainWindow` one. This does not make sense to me. From my understanding, `QDialog` can be either modal or modeless, and I believe my current implementation has the modal set. With that in mind, PyCharm says self is QMainWindow so I assume that it is inheriting the parent which should prevent a second Taskbar entry from populating. Perhaps I'm wrong about that.

The other issue I have is accessing elements of the `QDialog` and variables when it has been implemented as a class, I'm not entire sure how to do that, and my research has not really explained things in a easy to understand way.

What would be the best way to approach this, and how can I prevent the `QDialog` from creating a second taskbar entry?

Comment: It looks as if you are using the returned widget wrong. You are supposed to run "setupUI" on a given widget, in your case an instance of QDialog. See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#the-uic-module

Comment: @ deets after reading over the documentation, would that imply that I need to compile the UI files using pyuic5, import them as `from ui_file import ui_class`? This approach does not seem very economical as my application is still under development, and changes to the UI file are happening rapidly, so loading the UI files directly removes a lot of steps. Also, I'm assigned the UI file for the `QDialog` to `self.exampleDialog` so I can access objects within the UI file, although that doesn't really seem right to me, and I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: No, that's not what it means. The documentation is a bit unclear, but it shouldn't matter if you instantiate yourself, or use loadUIC to obtain an instance. But this then needs in both cases setupUi. Also, even if you had to use pyuic, this would just be a build-step after ui-modification. Regarding you second question: why doesn't that feel right? If you want to access things, you have to have them accesible. I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Your right about the documentation not being exactly clear. It seems to me that in order to use `setupUi()` you have to compile the UI file instead of directly using it in your project. I say this because in every example I have seen, `setupUi()` is inherited from the compiled UI file. The reason this doesn't feel right has a lot to do with using getters and setters to perform this type of work. It feels hackish, but if implemented as a class, how would I go about accessing objects in the UI file? I assume a series of setters and getters would be one way, but is it the best way?

Comment: Please no getters and setters! Python is not Java! Your access to the widgets in question is based on their name, which is exactly the right way to do it, as it decouples the points of interaction of your surrounding code from the inner structure of the widget. Python allows for a more powerful property-concept to work here than other languages, thus you get your "dialog.widgetName"-pattern. BTW I would follow python naming conventions for widget names, because now they look like class-names. And of course more semantic naming - ComboBox is a type, not a concrete list of e.g. countries.

Comment: The documentation is perfectly clear. You can get the exact equivalent of the gui class generated by pyuic using [loadUiType](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#PyQt5.uic.loadUiType).

Comment: @ekhumoro I figured it out just before you posted, I'm making the changes to the initial question.

Comment: @deets After some more reading, I finally figured out what you were talking about. I seemed to have miss the part where you can compile the UI file at runtime using `uic.loadUiType('')[0]` and then run `self.setupUi(self)`. I have made the change to my Test.py above, but I'm still mucking around with the `QDialog` which still gives me a second taskbar entry.

Comment: @deets I have added the proposed changes to the example, with the example I am still able access elements from `TestExampleDialog.ui`, and I feel better about how this is laid out, but I'm still getting a second taskbar entry.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have made the updates as deets suggested, the issue with the second taskbar entry still remains.

Comment: @AaronTomason. Windows without a parent get their owm task bar entry.

Comment: @ekhumoro I see that `parent = None` in this example. I have tried changing it to `parent = QMainWindow`, `parent = MainWindow` neither of which have worked. I also tried changing `QDialog.__init__` to QMainWindow.__init__`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @AaronTomason. `self.exampleDialog = ExampleDialog(self)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried doing that using the example code above, and the dialog will not open, and no exception is thrown.

Comment: @AaronTomason. `self.exampleDialog.setWindowFlags(self.exampleDialog.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)`. (And you need to import `QDialog`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the issue completely. Assigning self to `self.exampleDialog = ExampleDialog(self)` and updating `self.exampleDialog.setWindowFlags` to include `self.exampleDialog.windowFlags()` eliminates the second taskbar entry.

Elements of the dialog can be accessed using `self.exampleDialog.<element>` for example `self.exampleDialog.setWindowTitle('Example Dialog')`

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow
import sys

Ui_MainWindow = uic.loadUiType('TestMainWindow.ui')[0]
Ui_ExampleDialog = uic.loadUiType('TestExampleDialog.ui')[0]


class ExampleDialog(QDialog, Ui_ExampleDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, flags = Qt.Dialog):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        self.setupUi(self)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, flags = Qt.Window):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent, flags)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('MCVE')

        # Assign 'self' to 'ExampleDialog' so we can
        # access elements of the dialog.
        self.exampleDialog = ExampleDialog(self)

        self.itemInfoBtn.clicked.connect(self.showExampleDialog)
        self.setupItemInfo()

    def showExampleDialog(self):
        self.exampleDialog.setWindowFlags(self.exampleDialog.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.exampleDialog.closeButton.clicked.connect(self.exampleDialog.accept)
        self.exampleDialog.exec_()  # CREATES A TASKBAR ENTRY ... BUT WHY?

    def setupItemInfo(self):
        val = {'Entry #3', 'Entry #2', 'Entry #1'}
        self.exampleDialog.setWindowTitle('Example Dialog')
        self.exampleDialog.exampleCombo.insertItems(0, val)
        self.exampleDialog.exampleCombo.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```